# Is it possible to get callback from Facebook server while adding image in own account ?

Tags: android

I am trying to get any notification or callback from facebook server while adding any images in own account.Is there any callback which will update me like images been added or removing form FB account.

Answer (score 0):

this gives you callback method. Whatever you want should happen after successful login you can write call method :)

```
private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
               // TODO
 }
}
```

Comment: I have one doubt this callback will called every time when Session has been changed.But I need only when gallery data has been changed.

Comment: In callback method check if number of images is changed what are you having now in if condition and them do what u want. 
Other approach can be  keep the fb token call web service check if images has changed do what you want :)